# How to get all long time zone names (like "Europe/Berlin")

Tags: javascript, timezone

I want to get an array of all time zone names, a browser understand to give the user the possibility to select one of them.

I know I could get the time zone names for the time zone, the user is currently in like so:

```js
    const browserLocale = new Intl.Locale(navigator.language);
    console.log(browserLocale.timeZones);
```

However I didn't find any function, which returns a full list of all time zone names, the browser understands. (This may differ from browser to browser and from version to version)

Here is my **really dumb** version to get all names:

```js
    function collectAllPossibleTimeZoneNames() {
      const az = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + i));
      const aazz = az.flatMap((a) => az.map((b) => a + b));
      const AAZZ = aazz.map((item) => item.toUpperCase());
      const aazzAAZZ = aazz.flatMap((a) => AAZZ.map((b) => `${a}-${b}`));

      const length = aazzAAZZ.length;
      let oldProgress = "";

      const timeZoneNames = aazzAAZZ.reduce(
        (set, currentLocale, index) => {
          const progress = ((index / length) * 100).toFixed(1);
          if (progress !== oldProgress) {
            oldProgress = progress;
            console.log(`${progress}%`);
          }
          const locale = new Intl.Locale(currentLocale);
          if (!locale || !locale.timeZones || locale.timeZones.length === 0) {
            return set;
          }
          locale.timeZones.forEach((timeZoneName) => set.add(timeZoneName));
          return set;
        },
        new Set(),
      );

      const timeZoneNamesArray = Array.from(timeZoneNames);
      timeZoneNamesArray.sort();
      return timeZoneNamesArray;
    }

    console.log(collectAllPossibleTimeZoneNames());
```

This solution is practically useless as it takes far too long (about 2 minutes on my System)
I could use a code like this once and store the result in a database but these names may differ for different users.

Any guesses so far?

Thank you

Comment: I think you are looking for [`Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/supportedValuesOf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and one-liner way to do this is with `Intl.supportedValuesOf()`

In your case: `Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')` returns an array of all the possible timezones.

[image]

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/supportedValuesOf

Comment: Good answer, but keep in mind these are only _some_ of the supported values.  Don't use it to pre-validate input.  Additional values include zone aliases, renamed zones, and administrative ("etc") zones.